# Add Defaults To Pdflatex?

Tags: pandoc, command-line

I would like pdflatex to default to using `-file-line-error`.  (Why is this not the default anyway??)  Is this possible?

I can add the flag into a bash alias on my own runs, but when I use pandoc, it invokes latex by itself.

This is not a major problem, but a nuisance.  For pandoc, I then generate tex and run the pdflatex myself.  Doable.

Comment: File-line error style is not the default because the original implementation of TeX did not use the file-line error style.

Comment: I've seen a lot of editors that can no longer parse the log file when that option was enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TeXLive you can change the default in the `texmf.cnf`. If you add to a local texmf.cnf (the default value in the main texmf.cnf is `f`)

```
 file_line_error_style = t
```

the error style changes to

```
./test-input.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
```

In MiKTeX open a local ini for the executable you want to change with

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex
```

and add there

```
[TeXandFriends]
  CStyleErrors = t
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make a small shell script wrapper that set that option and was before standard latex in the path as used by pandoc. (Changing the default in general isn't an option it would break far too many scripts and IDEs that are expecting a standard log format.)

Specifically for pandoc, an alternative, looking at the manual https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html would be to use the pandoc option

```
--pdf-engine-opt=-file-line-error
```